# Why is this SQL/DDL violating the wrong Integrity constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

So it is showing me that the first insert is failing IC4, but it should be good to go as far as IC2 is concerned. IC2 states that 'DB guru' should be above 200--which the first entry is!

For example you'll see that the first entry on the insert list below is:

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (10, 'Gray', 'DB guru', 240);
```

But this fails IC4... why?!

How do I specify that a CONSTRAINT has to apply to only a certain categorical value like I am attempting here? Am I missing an important notion with respect to the way that CHECK is implemented? I'm really new to SQL and trying to wrap my head around this:

```
SPOOL ddl.out
SET ECHO ON

--
-- IMPORTANT: use the names IC1, IC2, etc. as given below.
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------
/*The following DROP command is inserted for convenience so that if you need to recompile
your code, it will drop the table (if it already exists).
*/
DROP TABLE Employee CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Dependent CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
--
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
rank CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
salary INTEGER NOT NULL,
/*
IC1: The rank is one of: 'DB guru', 'DB expert', or 'DB rookie'
*/
CONSTRAINT IC1 CHECK (rank IN ('DB guru', 'DB expert', 'DB rookie')),
/*
IC2: The salary of a 'DB guru' is above 200.
*/
CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK (rank != 'DB guru' OR salary > 200),
/*
IC3: The salary of a 'DB expert' is between 80 and 220 (inclusive).
*/
CONSTRAINT IC3 CHECK (rank != 'DB expert' OR (salary >= 80 AND salary <= 220 )),
/*
IC4: The salary of a 'DB rookie' is less than 100.
*/
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (rank != 'DB rookie' OR salary < 100)
);
--
--
CREATE TABLE Dependent
(
empID INTEGER,
dependentName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
relationship CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (empID, dependentName),
/*
IC5: empID must refer to an employee in the company. Also:
if an employee is deleted then his/her dependents must be deleted.
IMPORTANT: DO NOT declare this IC as DEFERRABLE.
*/
CONSTRAINT IC5 FOREIGN KEY (empID) REFERENCES Employee(id)
          ON DELETE CASCADE
);
--
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------
-- TESTING THE SCHEMA
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (10, 'Gray', 'DB guru', 240);
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (20, 'Garland', 'DB guru', 190);
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (30, 'Edison', 'DB expert', 210);
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (40, 'Eckerd', 'DB expert', 70);
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (50, 'Roberts', 'DB rookie', 110);
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (60, 'Rush', 'DB rookie', 90);
SELECT * from Employee;
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Dependent VALUES (10, 'Grace', 'daughter');
INSERT INTO Dependent VALUES (10, 'George', 'son');
INSERT INTO Dependent VALUES (60, 'Reba', 'daughter');
INSERT INTO Dependent VALUES (15, 'Dustin', 'son');
SELECT * FROM Dependent;
--
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE id = 10;
SELECT * From Employee;
SELECT * FROM Dependent;
--
SET ECHO OFF
SPOOL OFF
```

edited: To show the working solution based on the correct answer selected below.

Comment: which insert is failing? what error?

Comment: I just updated it to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical implication `A->B` is expressed as `NOT A OR B`. For example

```
/*
IC2: The salary of a 'DB guru' is above 200.
*/
CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK (rank != 'DB guru' OR salary > 200),
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can make the constraints mutually exclusive like that. This might help you:

```
CHECK ((rank = 'DB guru' AND salary > 200) or
       (rank = 'DB expert' AND salary >= 80 AND salary <=220 ) or
        ....
```

Edit:
Also, your IC4 CHECK CONSTRAINT logic is wrong, it should be:

```
/*
IC4: The salary of a 'DB rookie' is less than 100.
*/
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (rank = 'DB rookie' AND salary < 100)
);
```

instead of:

```
/*
IC4: The salary of a 'DB rookie' is less than 100.
*/
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (rank = 'DB rookie' AND salary >= 100)
);
```

which makes the consolidated condition as:

```
CHECK ((rank = 'DB guru' AND salary > 200) or
       (rank = 'DB expert' AND salary >= 80 AND salary <=220 ) or
       (rank = 'DB rookie' AND salary < 100))
```

Comment: @GinoL . . . I think this is a better solution.  Your real problem is that you are setting up multiple constraints on two columns where you should have only one constraint with a more complex condition.

Comment: The logic of the compound statements is still incorrect though. The answer I chose as correct is the correct answer in this regard. In addition, I was able to run my code with the constraints mutually exclusive while using the insight that (P->Q) <-> (~P or Q).

Comment: I think you are mentioning incorrect logic for your IC4 constraint => (rank = 'DB rookie' AND salary >= 100).....        which should have been (rank = 'DB rookie' AND salary < 100)

Comment: I edited to show the working solution based on the correct answer stated by @Serg.

Comment: I edited my answer. The logic in this answer is not incorrect, your IC4 logic was incorrect already, which you had to fix anyway.
Note that in your selected answer's implementation, you fixed IC4 differently.